# Heroku with H2 Database

Tags: spring, heroku, h2, spring-social

This is related to running Craig Walls Spring Social Showcase on Heroku.  This application runs fine locally using an H2 in memory database.  When I deploy to Heroku, however, the database no longer works.  Is there something else that needs to be configured on the Heroku server to get the in memory database to run?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no H2 support on the Heroku server. So you can't use H2 as an in memory database.

You can get a list of supported databases [here](https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores)

I would recommend you to use Postgres as a database. [This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction) is a good starting point.

Comment: You mean you can only use H2 in memory, because the file mode is blocked by security settings for the free plan. They also force you to use their own Postgres database service, which is way to expensive. The free plan is ok for very small microservices.